# Trigger different repository when execute stage in a release pipeline - Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, stage

I have two repositories differents "Repo 1" and "Repo 2" the 2 repositories in Azure DevOps.

"Repo 1" have different release pipelines (see below)

- "release-pipeline-dev" -> Stage 1
- "release-pipeline-qa" -> Stage 1

I need this -> When I create a new release for "release-pipeline-qa -> Stage 1" this triggers the execution of Repo 2, but only this release pipeline.

Is it possible to achieve this? how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added more information on Answer 1.

Answer (score -1):

I have the repository 1 (**front-end-repository**), I want to create a release for "release-pipeline-qa" (only for this) and automatically trigger the execution of repository 2 (**repository-cypress-qa**) to run the test cases in cypress.

Front end repository with React (Below)
[image]

This is the example to run the test cases in cypress
[image]

both are independent repositories